# JavaScript Syntax Error with ASP.NET Variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, variables, backend

I have a JavaScript Variable that is set in my ASP.NET page as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var MyVarable = <%=ASPNETVarable%>;
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(MyVarable);
}
</script>
```

Now this is simplified and on the back end code ASPNETVarable is set as

```
protected string ASPNETVarable="My Backend Value";
```

The page loads & runs correctly, but in Visual Studio the line

```
 var MyVarable = <%=ASPNETVarable%>;
```

Shows that it's a "Syntax error", while it works, how do I remove this "syntax error" ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem when I build a JavaScript function in a user control. Because the control can be used several times, I use `function myFunction_<%= this.ClientID %>() { [...] }` to make the function name unique for the control itself. Basically, this error appears on all cases where you do not wrap your variable between `'` or `"`. However everything compiles and runs fine as desired. Annoying error.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var MyVarable = '<%=ASPNETVarable%>';
```

Comment: Yes that Removes the Syntax Error, but also changes the value, causing issues with the rest of the code (Jason Data)

Comment: While this is good for string values it will not work for number variables, or other cases. For instance I want to perform specific javascript, only when a boolean is set in my code-behind. So I do `if(<%= Convert.ToInt32(this.IsRequired) %>) [...]` that causes the same "Syntax Error" problem.