# Server-sided variable output within a style tag in the ASPX markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I got a user control that I want to style with a larger bunch of CSS. Because the control can be implemented several times into the website as well as the CSS can vary on dependent properties of the user control, I cannot use a global extern CSS. So I need a scoped CSS part that comes with the control itself. Unfortunately HTML5 scoped styles are not common yet, so this is out of question.

My idea: I want to use a style tag within my root `asp:Panel` of my user control to style specific parts of my control. With the generated client ID of the parent container I can define a strict scope of the CSS. I optain the generated ID with a server variable:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pRoot" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #<%= this.pRoot.ClientID %> .myClass { 
            background-color: magenta; 
            width: 100px; 
            height: 100px; 
        }
    </style>
    <asp:Panel ID="pTest" runat="server" CssClass="myClass" />
</asp:Panel>
```

<strike>Now this will not work as it assumes `<%= this.pRoot.ClientID %>` is CSS, too. 
I know a static parent ID or code behind mechanics can solve this specific case, anyways.</strike>

So I just wonder:

**Is there a way to get a server sided variable into my style part of my markup without using code behind?**

**EDIT: It turned out, that the above example will work. Visual Studio just tells me the above example is not valid HTML. Annoying error, makes the same problems [just as using server sided variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662079/javascript-syntax-error-with-asp-net-variable). Microsoft, something has to be done about that.**

**Any idea to get rid of this error?**

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to page level methods and properties:

```
<%# propertyName %>

<%# MethodName() %>
```

both implemented in your page class.

The ID could come from server side anyway.